# MouseClicked not triggered for JTable in a GUI with both Action and Mouse Listener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, jbutton

I have a GUI in java swing with a JTable and JButtons that implements both ActionListener and MouseListener. I use both because ActionListener cannot be registered for JTable.  If I select a row of the JTable  and press the JButton "Delete", a row must be deleted. This works only for the first time I press delete.  The next time I select a row, mouseListener does not seem to be triggered. I print the selected row number whenever I click on the JTable.  If I consecutively click on the JTable the row gets printed correctly.  But if I press one of the buttons(that trigger ActionPerformed) and then JTable mouseClicked is not called. What is wrong here??

Thanks in Advance

Posting the code:

```
private void createTable(){
     tableModel=new SimpleTableModel(row);
     //SimpleTableModel populates the table model from vector
     jTable1 = new JTable(tableModel);
     jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

     jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
     jTable1.addMouseListener(this);
     //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
     add(jScrollPane1);
     this.repaint();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt) && evt.getSource() == jTable1) {
        selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        ruleId = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
        System.out.println("You have selected row=" + selectedRow
                + " with ruleId=" + ruleId);
    }
}
```

More code (suggested by kleopatra - i just added it inside a method doAction() with some changes):

```
private void doAction() {
    Action delete = new AbstractAction("Delete Selected Row") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*
             * if (jTable1.getSelectedRow() < 0) return; int modelRowIndex =
             * jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
             * ((DefaultTableModel)
             * jTable1.getModel()).removeRow(modelRowIndex);
             * 
             * Since I use a tableModel (which is a class named
             * SimpleTableModel) that inherits AbstractTableModel,
             * ClassCastException popped up. So I used normal code.
             */
            selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
            System.out.println("Selected row:" + selectedRow);
            if (selectedRow == -1) {
                System.out
                        .println("Select a row in the table before clicking \"Delete\"");
                return;
            }
            row.remove(selectedRow);
            createTable();
        }
    };
    JButton button = new JButton(delete);
}
```

Here's the complete code:

```
public class Data {


      private String a; 

      private String b;

      private String c;

      private String d;

      private String e;



      public Data() {
      }

      public Data(String aa, String bb, String cc, String dd,String ee) {
        setA(aa);
        setB(bb);
        setC(cc);
        setD(dd);
        setE(ee);
      }     


    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setE(String e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public String getE() {
        return e;
    }
}


public class SimpleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
public String[] colNames = { "AA","BB","CC","DD","EE"};


public Class[] colTypes ={String.class, String.class, String.class,String.class,String.class };


Vector dataVector;


public SimpleTableModel(Vector dataVector) {
  super();
  this.dataVector = dataVector;
} 

public int getColumnCount() {
    return colNames.length;
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return colNames[column];
}


    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataVector.size();
      }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Data macData = (Data) (dataVector.elementAt(rowIndex));

          switch (columnIndex) {
          case 0:
            return macData.getA();
          case 1:
            return macData.getB();
          case 2:
            return macData.getC();
          case 3:
            return macData.getD();
          case 4:
              return macData.getE();

          }

          return new String();
        }
}

public class DisplayGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JTable jTable1;
private JButton jButton1;
private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private SimpleTableModel tableModel;
static Vector<Data> row=new Vector<Data>(10,10);
static int selectedRow;
public DisplayGUI(){
    initComponents();
}
private void initComponents(){

    jButton1 =new JButton();
    jButton1.setText("Delete");
    jButton1.addActionListener(this);
    row.addElement(new Data("abc","bcd","cde","def","efg"));
    row.addElement(new Data("1","2","3","4","5"));
    row.addElement(new Data("10","11","12","13","14"));
    createTable();
    add(jButton1);
}


private void createTable() {
    tableModel=new SimpleTableModel(row);
     jTable1 = new JTable(tableModel);
      jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
      add(jScrollPane1);
        this.repaint();
}


public static void main(String[] args){
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("DisplayGUI");
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        DisplayGUI newContentPane = new DisplayGUI();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

    if(evt.getSource()==jButton1){
        selectedRow=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        System.out.println("You have selected "+selectedRow);
        if(selectedRow==-1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Select a row in the 
                                                   table before clicking \"Delete\"",
                    "Alert!",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        row.remove(selectedRow);
        createTable();
    }
}

}
```

Did the following changes to make my code working:

```
 private void initComponents(){

jButton1 =new JButton();
jButton1.setText("Delete");
jButton1.addActionListener(this);
row.addElement(new Data("abc","bcd","cde","def","efg"));
row.addElement(new Data("1","2","3","4","5"));
row.addElement(new Data("10","11","12","13","14"));
tableModel=new SimpleTableModel(row);
jTable1 = new JTable(tableModel);
 jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
 jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
 add(jScrollPane1);
 add(jButton1);
 createTable();

}


private void createTable() {
 tableModel.setDataVector(row);
//Added a setDataVector method to class Data
 jTable1.setModel(tableModel);

    this.repaint();
 }


/*Also, added a condition jTable1.getRowCount()==0 to check for empty table before    
*deleting in actionPerformed.
*/
```

Comment: something wrong with the code you'r not showing ;-)

Comment: Change the '.' on column 42 of line 42 to a ','.  That should fix the problem.  If not, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: Sorry here's the code...                                    tableModel=new SimpleTableModel(row);                   //SimpleTableModel populates the table model from vector
jTable1 = new JTable(tableModel);
    jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    
jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
jTable1.addMouseListener(this);
//Add the scroll pane to this panel.
add(jScrollPane1);
this.repaint();

Comment: @Niranjani S Please edit the code into your question. And try making as 'full' as possible we everyone can try to runn and test it for him/her self.

Comment: @Niranjani S one note here, from experience and from what I remember being written somewhere (maybe even in Java doc) you shouldn't relay on using mouseClicked, use mousePressed or mouseReleased instead.

Comment: @Niranjani S please give us more code in this one all appears to be fine. As kleopatra suspects it might be something to do with the way you remove the rows.

Comment: don't use any low-level listener until you have to. Here you don't have to.

Comment: Maybe the error is in using AbstractTableModel instead of DefaultTableModel.  But how come the first time it deletes the row but on clicking **another different** row it returns selected row as -1.

Comment: sorry to be blunt - but your code is either completely crazy or different from what you are showing or both: you re-create the table at the end of deleting the selected row? no wonder nothing is selected. My guess is that the field jTable1 set in createTable is different from jTable1 in doAction, this being the case, the action acts on the old while the visible is a completely new one. And remove that d*** MouseListener, you don't need it.

Comment: yeah, your code _is_ completely crazy (no offense meant, though), see my comment in my answer as well. Hints a) never-ever recreate a JTable (if that seems necessary, something is severly wrong) b) never-ever touch the data-structure that's backing a TableModel (doing so is most of the "severely wrong" here ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a MouseListener anywhere, simply let the button's Action query the table's selection state, something like

```
    Action delete = new AbstractAction("Delete Selected Row") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (table.getSelectedRow() < 0) return;
            int modelRowIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel().removeRow(modelRowIndex);
        }
    };
    JButton button = new JButton(delete);
```

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you for immediate reply.  Your code seems to work the first time. But the second or subsequent try always returns the selectedRow as -1.

Comment: @Niranjani that's probably because there _is no_ selection - the code removed the selected row :-)

Comment: @kleopatra The javadoc for getSelectedRow() says it returns the "index of the first selected row"; so for subsequent clicks on button Delete, getSelectedRow() returns -1 even if some other valid row is selected before clicking it(Delete).

Comment: @Niranjani - nothing wrong with the doc, only with your code (see my comment to your question).

Comment: @Niranjani, what do you expect me to do? It's _your_ job to get it running, so first thing would be you take my advice (all! of it). BTW, your implementation of TableModel is completely wrong (and that's probably why you think you need to re-create the complete table) Start simple, read the tutorial, use default classes that come with Swing instead of rolling your own ..

Comment: @kleoptra Thank you for the observation that I'm creating a new JTable and that the actionListener is listening the previous table while I'm creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ListSelectionListener on the tables selection model to respond to selection changes, not a MouseListener.

Comment: hach ... last must turn off the light on OTN :-)

Comment: Well the mouse listener might still be useful. Using ListSelectionListener you will get the row only if you change the currently selected one. It all depends on the code we are implementing.

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah, not enough activity there to keep me distracted from work :P